# file_get_contents Adding numbers from 2 text files

Tags: php, file-get-contents, addition

I'm currently using a cronjob to cache a number into text from an API, I have two text files with numbers in them and I want to add both together like 16+4 and it prints at 20

I have no Idea how I would do this and would be really glad if someone could provide an example if It can be done.

Comment: uh, you mean like this? `echo trim(file_get_contents('file1.txt')) + trim(file_get_contents('file2.txt'));` I  have a sneaking suspicion you are dumbing it down too much for us

Comment: Great **"one-liner"** @CrayonViolent +1

Comment: Crayon I missed your comment at first but that works perfect too and its a smaller code. Basically I have a competition running from an API and they messed something up, so there making a second team to run and want to add that person in without messing stuff up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
<?php

$file1 = '/path/to/file/file1.txt';
$file2 = '/path/to/file/file2.txt';

if(is_file($file1) && is_file($file2)) {

    $value1 = trim(file_get_contents($file1));
    $value2 = trim(file_get_contents($file2));

    echo sprintf('The sum is %s', (int)$value1 + (int)$value2);

} else {
    echo "One of the files doesn't exist";
}
```