# Building a discount code system using PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a simple flat file database based discount code system. So the users get to the checkout page and they can enter a given code and the amount related to that code will be deducted from the final value of the shopping cart. It's nothing complicated.

I can do the deduction etc. but I'm confused because I'm using a flat file database and I don't have a clue if things like `SELECT, WHERE clause` etc will work in a flat file database. And for that reason, I cannot relate the discount code to its amount to be deducted.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if (isset($_POST['disCode'])) {
    $disCode = $_POST['disCode'];
    $arr=file("FlatFile1.txt");

    foreach($arr as $str)
    {
        list($code,$amount)=explode("|",$str);
    }
    
    $Total =  $Total - $disCode;
}
```

As you can see in the code above, I use `$Total =  $Total - $disCode;`, so if i put a number (example 10 or 5 or any other number), and submit the form, it will take off (deduct) that amount from the `$Total`.

But I need to use the `$code` which is pulled from the `FlatFile1.txt` file and then deduct the `$amount` related to that `$code` from the `$Total`.

The flat file structure is like so:

```
RFHSEP34 | 20 

RETBBHUJ | 10 

TYRHBNNM | 5
```

The first part is the `$code` that will be given to the users and the second part after `|` is the `$amount` that will be deducted from the `$Total` is the $code is entered.

### Edit

I've edited my code to the following. I am getting close to what I want but it doesn't matter what I type in the input field (disCode), I always get the `$amount` of the last discount code deducted from the `$Total`!

```
    $arr=file("flatFile1.txt");

    foreach($arr as $str)
    {
        list($code,$amount)=explode("|",$str);
    }


if (isset($_POST['disCode'])) {
    $disCode = $_POST['disCode'];

    if ($disCode = $code)
    {
        $fDis = $amount;
        $Total =  $Total - $fDis;
    
    }
}
```

What can I do to resolve this?

To re-produce my issue, you can create a .txt file and call it `flatFile1.txt`. and then use the flat file code above in that file. and then create a simple php page with my last code in it. and finally create a simple form with an input field named `disCode` and simple submit button on the same .php page.

As for the value of `$Total` you can simply use the following:

`$Total = 50;` or `$Total = '50';`

### Edit 2

I have been spending far too long for such simple function with no avail so I will give up on it if I can't get an answer to this final edit.

I will paste the entire code from my php page so there won't any confusion!

```
<?php
$Total = 500;
$arr=file("flatFile1.txt");

foreach($arr as $str){
    list($code,$amount)=explode("|",$str);
}
if (isset($_POST['disCode'])) {
    $disCode = $_POST['disCode'];

    if ($disCode == $code)
    {
        $Total -= $amount;
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="disDiv"><form action="carttest" method="post">
    
        <input type="text" name="disCode"/><br /><br />
        
        <input TYPE="image" SRC="discountBtn.png"
        BORDER="0" name="discountCode" id="disCount" class="disCount" /></form></div><br />
        
        
        <?php echo $Total; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above doesn't work at all. which means it does not deduct the `$amount` from the `$Total`.

However, if I change the `if ($disCode == $code)` to `if ($disCode = $code)`, it will deduct the last `$amount` in the *flatFile.txt* without typing anything in the disCode inputfield. so i just need to submit the form and the amount will be deduced which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/22123737/ and base yourself on that.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, but that only shows how to add up numbers together in two files! doesn't explain anything related to my question! especially the WHERE, SELECT etc... unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry, the `WHERE, SELECT` threw me off. To answer your question, that I don't know how to do using a flatfile and a DB. I usually do one or the other. See the answers given below.

Comment: You could probably use the total's variable from your text file and compare it with a `WHERE`, something to the effect of `SELECT something FROM table WHERE column='$Total'`, that's about the best I can think of.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, so I can use the WHERE as well if i'm using a flat file (.txt file) as a database?

Comment: I would imagine yes; theoretically it can be done. Just as long as you first get the results from your flatfile, then use that (final) variable to be passed on to your query, then compare the matches with both.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce what your results are with the code you posted. Tried to find a solution for you in conjunction with DB but results are always inconclusive. Is that your actual/full code and its usage?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I have edited my question with my new edited code. any ideas on that? also, thank you so much for trying to help mate, much appreciate it. yes, that is my actual code with its usage. I get the values from the flatFile.txt and then use it like the my code above.

Comment: These two variables `$code,$amount` where are they being defined? That's why I'm unable to recreate it, because I don't know what they're assigned as, or what should be assigned as. Plus, your conditional statement `if ($disCode = $code)` is incorrect; it should be `if ($disCode == $code)`. With a single `=` you're assigning instead of comparing `==`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, the $code and $amount are pulled from the .txt file. if you copy this `RFHSEP34 | 20` in a .txt file and name that .txt file `flatFile1.txt` and use my PHP code and simply use `echo $code`, `echo $amount`.. you will see how they are defined and you should get them echo-ed on your php page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$discount = 0; //set initial discount as zero
foreach($arr as $str)

{

list($code[],$amount[])=explode("|",$str); //$code & $amount should be array 

}

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($code);$i++){ 
    if (trim(strtoupper($code[$i]))==trim(strtoupper($disCode))){ 
        $discount=$amount[$i]; //Found
    }
}

$Total =  $Total - $discount;
```

Comment: This almost does what I want but for some reason, when i try to checkout with paypal and when I get directed to paypal, i get an error in the paypal saying "Error: your cart is empty"! this only happens if I apply the discount code using the code above! without doing that it works fine. any suggestions?

Comment: More information is needed regarding the paypal submission before anyone could suggest a solution. I can't if assume the code snippet above is part of the whole paypal submit action or another function that needs to return the `$Total`

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you, this should work:

```
<?php
$Total = 500;

if (isset($_POST['disCode'])) {
    $arr = file('flatfile1.txt');
    $disCode = strtoupper(trim($_POST['disCode']));

    $found = false;
    foreach($arr as $str)
    {
        // Skip empty or invalid lines (assuming your file flatfile1.txt has blank lines).
        if (strpos($str, '|') === false)
            continue;

        list($code,$amount) = explode('|',$str);
        if ($disCode === trim($code))
        {
            // Code found.
            $Total -= $amount;
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$found)
        echo "Code $disCode not found.";
    else
        echo "Discounted total: $Total (discount: $amount).";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="disDiv"><form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="disCode"/><br /><br />

        <input TYPE="image" SRC="discountBtn.png"
        BORDER="0" name="discountCode" id="disCount" class="disCount" /></form></div><br />


        <?php echo "Total: $Total"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

As last note, if your codes have fixed length you can limit te maximum characters on input box.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't do anything. neither does it deduct an amount nor does it throw any error.

Comment: This code loop thorugh all codes (`file()` read a file into an array, one row per item) and break when loop if found. If `$discount` is null the discount code does not exist and you must put your code in the `if` block with comment.

Comment: also, I did try a simple `echo "that code doesn't exist";` in the `if` statemnet as you said but I always get that error thrown out on the page and it doesn't deduct the `$discount` from the `$Total`! i double checked to make sure the flat File has the code in it and the code is 100% in there. any suggestion on that?

Comment: My code work, I've tested it. Please check that: your post request has `disCode` key on `$_POST[]`, you _can reach_ `FlatFile1.txt`, `$arr` will be properly filled. P.S.: code on your EDIT question is wrong please see [php manual on list()](http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and you must use == or === on `if ($disCode = $code)` block. You get always last discount because list overwrite `$code` and `$amount` for each $arr element.

Comment: How did you test your code? I've tried testing it in a separate clean php code with no other codes in it and still doesn't work! can you please provide your test code (the code that you said worked) including the html and txt file? i need to see if I'm missing something.

Comment: I have updated and tested the code (in localhost) to check for _blank lines_ on `flatfile1.txt` and edited `action="..."` attribute. You can remove example `echo`s if you want.